# .bash_profile statements get executed twice

Tags: windows, msysgit

I use MsysGit on windows 7. I have one annoying problem. The entire bash_profile file seems to get executed twice. 
for example, I have the following echo line in the .bash_profile

```
echo "Boinkk..."
```

[image]

If I have

```
echo "Calvin..."
echo "Hobbes..."
```

Then I get [image]
So I know that the .bash_profile file is getting executed twice and not each statement getting executed twice. 
The target for the "Git Bash" Executable is

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files\Software\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"
```

Does anybody know what I have to do to get the bash shell to execute the bash_profile statements only once?

Comment: because if each statement was getting executed twice, I should have got 
Calvin...
Calvin...
Hobbes...
Hobbes...

Comment: Do you have any other rc files like bashrc that source bash_profile?  I don't think it would do anything but try removing the `-i` from your target.

Comment: @jw013 I tried removing `-i`, didn't help. I also tried removing `--login -i`, but then .bash_profile didn't get sourced at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with how to fix on Windows but if it were UNIX/Linux you could do:

```
echo $PATH <br />
```

and see where you're getting your double entry from. I'm speculating that your .bash_profile is being added to the path more than once. If you track down where the path is being manipulated you can fix your problem.

Comment: @Prasanth Can you share what the fix was? I tried `echo $PATH <br />`, `echo "$0"`, `echo "$BASH_SOURCE"` to try to find what was sourcing .bash_profile twice, but no luck. I have no .bashrc files. It appears to me that Git Bash is sourcing ~/.bash_profile twice when it starts.

Comment: Git bash was sourcing my .bash_profile already. That was my problem. Ive long since moved to a Unix set up.

Comment: The <br /> part didn't work for me (is that PHP?).  Assuming this command is used to delimit the output, I had better luck running:  echo $PATH | tr : \\n

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and noticed there was no ~/.bashrc file.

**Creating an empty ~/.bashrc** resolved the issue:

```
touch ~/.bashrc
```

I could only speculate as to why this worked, but it did.

Comment: This also mysteriously worked for me using Git Bash on Windows. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR — try removing `--login` from your bash invocation**

---

If you're using Git for Windows with ConEmu or Cmder, the command to start bash probably looks something like this:

```
cmd /c ""%ConEmuDir%\..\git-for-windows\bin\bash" -i --login"
```

Note the `--login` bit. [Apparently](https://askubuntu.com/a/445015/166987), if `--login` is passed to bash, it will *first* execute the commands from `/etc/profile`, *then* execute one of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, or `~/.profile` — whichever exists.

Now, msys provides an `/etc/profile`, which executes all scripts under `/etc/profile.d`. Cmder offers `/etc/profile.d/cmder.sh`, which executes `~/.bashrc` (excerpt below)

```
# Source the users .bashrc file if it exists
if [ -f "${HOME}/.bashrc" ] ; then
    . "${HOME}/.bashrc"
fi
```

That's all done within the execution of `/etc/profile`. Afterward, `bash --login` will try to execute `~/.bash_profile`. Git for Windows generates this `~/.bash_profile`:

```
# generated by Git for Windows
test -f ~/.profile && . ~/.profile
test -f ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc
```

Upon execution, `~/.bashrc` gets run a second time.

Solution? **Remove `--login` from bash's invocation**. In Cmder/ConEmu, this can be done by hitting the down-arrow next to the plus button, finding your bash in the list, and changing the command to:

```
cmd /c ""%ConEmuDir%\..\git-for-windows\bin\bash" -i"
```

Without the `--login` bit, bash will skip executing `/etc/profile`, and only run `~/.bashrc` (... and `/etc/bash.bashrc`, but msys doesn't execute the `~/.bashrc` there)

---